# Flattening Postgres nested JSONB column

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm looking to see how to flatten data nested in a JSONB column.
As an example, say we have the table users with user_id(int) and siblings(JSONB)

With rows like:

```
id | JSONB
---------------------
1  | {"brother": {"first_name":"Sam", "last_name":"Smith"}, "sister": {"first_name":"Sally", "last_name":"Smith"}
2  | {"sister": {"first_name":"Jill"}}
```

I'm looking for a query that will return a response like:

```
id | sibling   | first_name | last_name
-------------------------------------
1  | "brother" | "Sam"      | "Smith"
1  | "sister"  | "Sally"    | "Smith"
2  | "sister"  | "Jill"     | null
```

Comment: postgres version?

Comment: @VaoTsun version 9.4.9

Comment: json keys first_name and last_name are constant?..

Comment: @VaoTsun no, the keys could change

Comment: then wait for someone else. I can help to get ` id |    sibling    |    key     |   value` easily, but then you need `tablefunc` to make crosstab, and I can create extension... or it's obvious how to get your result with known key... btw - update your question to reflect that

Comment: @JacobMurphy If the keys can change, meaning `first_name` and such, this is a bad candidate for turning into fixed columns. Can you define a set of keys you want to turn into columns and leave the rest as JSON?

Answer (score 2):

I develop to this use it in `psql`. 
To check code I create small view `t1`:

```
CREATE VIEW t1 AS (
       SELECT 1 AS id, '{"brother": {"first_name":"Sam", "last_name":"Smith"}, "sister": {"first_name":"Sally", "last_name":"Smith"}}'::jsonb AS jsonb
 UNION SELECT 2, '{"sister": {"first_name":"Jill", "last_name":"Johnson"}}'
 UNION SELECT 3, '{"sister": {"first_name":"Jill", "x_name":"Johnson"}}'
);
```

The first task is to found list of possible key:

```
WITH fields AS (
     SELECT DISTINCT jff.key
       FROM t1,
            jsonb_each(jsonb) AS jf,
            jsonb_each(jf.value) AS jff
)
SELECT * FROM fields;
```

The result is:

```
    key     
------------
 first_name
 last_name
 x_name
```

The next step is generate queries:

```
SELECT 'SELECT id, jf.key as sibling, ' || (
    WITH fields AS (
         SELECT DISTINCT jff.key
           FROM t1,
                jsonb_each(jsonb) AS jf,
                jsonb_each(jf.value) AS jff
    )
    SELECT string_agg('jf.value->>''' || key || ''' as "' || key || '"', ',' ORDER BY key)
      FROM fields
)
|| ' FROM t1, jsonb_each(jsonb) AS jf ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;' AS cmd;
```

It returns:

```
                                                                                  cmd                                                                                   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SELECT id, jf.key as sibling,jf.value->>'first_name' as "first_name",jf.value->>'last_name' as "last_name",jf.value->>'x_name' as "x_name" FROM t1, jsonb_each(jsonb) AS jf ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
(1 row)
```

To set result as psql variable I use `gset`:

```
\gset
```

After that you can call query:

```
:cmd

 id | sibling | first_name | last_name | x_name  
----+---------+------------+-----------+---------
  1 | brother | Sam        | Smith     | 
  1 | sister  | Sally      | Smith     | 
  2 | sister  | Jill       | Johnson   | 
  3 | sister  | Jill       |           | Johnson
(4 rows)
```

To run it from external languages you can create postgres function than return SQL command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION build_query(IN tname text, OUT cmd text)  AS $sql$
BEGIN 
    EXECUTE $cmd$
            SELECT 'SELECT id, jf.key as sibling, ' || (
                    WITH fields AS (
                        SELECT DISTINCT jff.key
                          FROM t1,
                               jsonb_each(jsonb) AS jf,
                               jsonb_each(jf.value) AS jff
                    )
                    SELECT string_agg('jf.value->>''' || key || ''' as "' || key || '"', ',' ORDER BY key)
                      FROM fields
                )
        || ' FROM $cmd$ || quote_ident(tname) || $cmd$ , jsonb_each(jsonb) AS jf ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;'$cmd$ INTO cmd;
    RETURN;
END;
$sql$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM build_query('t1');
                                                                                               cmd                                                                                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 SELECT id, jf.key as sibling, jf.value->>'first_name' as "first_name",jf.value->>'last_name' as "last_name",jf.value->>'x_name' as "x_name" FROM t1 , jsonb_each(jsonb) AS jf ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
(1 row)
```

Comment: nice, but this is not recursive and do select only level 0+1 json nodes, or hang if one row miss a 0+1 json level: