# Json Arrays of objects PostgreSQL Table format

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a JSON file (array of objects) which I have to convert into a table format using a PostgreSQL query.

*Follow Sample Data.*
**"b", "c", "d", "e"**  are to be extracted as separate tables as they are arrays and in these arrays, there are objects

I have tried using `json_populate_recordset()` but it only works if I have a single array.

```json
[{a:"1",b:"2"},{a:"10",b:"20"}]
```

I have referred to some links and codes.

[jsonb_array_element example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42620281/how-to-convert-a-nested-json-column-from-postgresql-database-to-dataframe-with-p)

[postgreSQL functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.htmlhttps://)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZPfk.png)

```
Sample Data: 

    { 
       "b":[ 
           {columnB1:value, columnB2:value},
           {columnB1:value, columnB2:value},
        ],
       "c":[
           {columnC1:value, columnC2:value, columnC3:value},
           {columnC1:value, columnC2:value, columnC3:value},
           {columnC1:value, columnC2:value, columnC3:value}
        ],
        "d":[
           {columnD1:value, columnD2:value},
           {columnD1:value, columnD2:value},
        ],
       "e":[
           {columnE1:value, columnE2:value},
          
        ]
    }
```

expected output

**b** should be one table in which columnA1 and columnA2 are displayed with their values.
Similarly **table c, d, e** with their respective columns and values.

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZPfk.png)

Comment: What does the expected output look like?

Comment: I don't understand "are supposed to be separate sheets" - relational databases have no "sheets". Please **[edit]** your question and add the expected output. It will probably help if you provide more than one row of sample input data. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Sample data doesn't look like json format, is it supposed to be?

Comment: I have made some changes so it will be easy to understand. Please help me find some way around to extract these tables from Json file.

Comment: Yes I have checked, its a json file with multiple array of objects in it.

Comment: Your "expected" output doesn't make much sense; this is not relational data as would be expected as output from a RDBMS like postgres. What even is the format of that, CSV? A string? The closest to returning a postgres table format would be returning 4 tables, that is, doing 4 queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I came up with some ideas, here is one that worked. I was able to get one table at a time.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

I am using json_populate_recordset.

The column used in the first select statement comes from a table whose column is a JSON type which we are trying to extract into a table.
[image: Column4]

The 'tablename from column' in the json_populate_recordset function, is the table we are trying to extract followed with b its columns and datatypes.
[image: input for json function]

```
WITH input AS(
   SELECT cast(column as json) as a
   FROM tablename
)
SELECT b.*
FROM input c,
            json_populate_recordset(NULL::record,c.a->'tablename from column') as b(columnname1 datatype, columnname2 datatype)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jsonb_to_recordset()` but you need to unnest your JSON.  You need to do this inline as this is a [JSON Processing Function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) which cannot used derived values.

I am using validated JSON as simplified and formatted at end of this answer

To unnest your JSON use below notation which [extracts JSON object field](https://Extracts%20JSON%20object%20field%20with%20the%20given%20key.) with the given key.

```
--one level
select '{"a":1}'::json->'a' 
result : 1
--two levels
select '{"a":{"b":[2]}}'::json->'a'->'b'
result : [2]
```

We now expand this to include `json_to_recordset()`

```
select * from 
json_to_recordset(
  '{"a":{"b":[{"f1":2,"f2":4},{"f1":3,"f2":6}]}}'::json->'a'->'b' --inner table b 
) 
as x("f1" int, "f2" int); --fields from table b
```

or using `json_array_elements`.  Either way we need to list our fields.  With second solution type will be `json` not `int` so you cant sum etc

```
with b as (select json_array_elements('{"a":{"b":[{"f1":2,"f2":4},{"f1":3,"f2":6}]}}'::json->'a'->'b') as jx)
select jx->'f1' as f1, jx->'f2' as f2 from b;
```

Output

```
f1  f2
2   4
3   6
```

We now use your data structure in `jsonb_to_recordset()`

```
select * from jsonb_to_recordset( '{"a":{"b":[{"columnname1b":"value1b","columnname2b":"value2b"},{"columnname1b":"value","columnname2b":"value"}],"c":[{"columnname1":"value","columnname2":"value"},{"columnname1":"value","columnname2":"value"},{"columnname1":"value","columnname2":"value"}]}}'::jsonb->'a'->'b') as x(columnname1b text, columnname2b text);
```

Output:

```
columnname1b    columnname2b
value1b         value2b
value           value
```

For table `c`

```
select * from jsonb_to_recordset( '{"a":{"b":[{"columnname1b":"value1b","columnname2b":"value2b"},{"columnname1b":"value","columnname2b":"value"}],"c":[{"columnname1":"value","columnname2":"value"},{"columnname1":"value","columnname2":"value"},{"columnname1":"value","columnname2":"value"}]}}'::jsonb->'a'->'c') as x(columnname1 text, columnname2 text);
```

Output

```
columnname1 columnname2
value   value
value   value
value   value
```

Sample JSON

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": [
      {
        "columnname1b": "value1b",
        "columnname2b": "value2b"
      },
      {
        "columnname1b": "value",
        "columnname2b": "value"
      }
    ],
    "c": [
      {
        "columnname1": "value",
        "columnname2": "value"
      },
      {
        "columnname1": "value",
        "columnname2": "value"
      },
      {
        "columnname1": "value",
        "columnname2": "value"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```